# Xbee end nodes need a router to communicate with coordinator

Tags: xbee

I have a network of Series 2 Xbees: one coordinator, one router and two end nodes (one end node receives data, the other sends).  If the device with the router is turned off, the communication between the coordinator and the end nodes doesn't happen.  The router and the coordinator are in the same room, so I don't think it's a signal strength issue.  I reset the coordinator and the end nodes and they still don't communicate.  They are all on the same PAN ID.

Any suggestions/tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the SC parameter on the coordinator (command ATSC).
Make sure all modules are programmed with the same mask.

You can try to send the command ATNR0 to all modules too, so that all of them leave their current networks and restart the association process.